# Is using min/max on boolean lists in Python bad?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a condition I want to happen only when all items in a list evaluate to true. An example of this might be something like a list of functions which return a boolean (not actually my situation but easier to explain):

```
def foo():
    # do something
def bar():
    # do something
def baz():
    # do something

fncs = [foo, bar, baz]
if <every element in [fnc() for fnc in fncs] evaluates to true>:
    # do something
```

I know I can definitely do this:

```
all_true = True
for fnc in fncs:
    if not fnc():
        all_true = False
if all_true:
    # do something
```

But, I was wondering if this is poor form:

```
if min([fnc() for fnc in fncs]):
    # do something
```

Alternatively, I could try to select all false elements during list comprehension and check whether the list is occupied (this works because bool(arr) where arr is a list returns False if and only if arr is empty):

```
if not [None for fnc in fncs if not fnc()]:
    # do something
```

I feel like the "min" is a lot cleaner than the last method, and while the first one is easiest to understand for novices it should be pretty clear what's going on. I could alternately make it clearer through aliasing:

```
all_true = min
if all_true([fnc() for fnc in fncs]):
    # do something
```

I'm sure I missed other ways to do this as well. I'm wondering what method would be most desirable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Most languages have an `every` function that checks if every item in the list satisfies a predicate. I imagine python has such a function.

Comment: Use the `all` function to see if everything in an iterable is true.

Comment: There is also `any` which checks if any of the items in an iterable are true

Comment: Python has the built in functions `all()` and `any()` for this exact purpose. Use them. Edit: wasn't quick enough it seems!)

Comment: Here's a list of pythons built in functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions

Comment: @PatrickHaugh oh, of course. Second item on the python built-in functions list... https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html thanks for pointing me to this!

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `foo() and bar() and baz()`?

Comment: Haha I guess a serious case of overengineering here... Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @MSeifert in this contrived example sure. If the list of functions are passed into a function or something then that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `min` is not "bad", but it *is* unclear what you are trying to do and will do unnecessary work. You should use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead.

```
if all(fnc() for fnc in fncs):
    # do something
```

This will return `True` if all values are `True`, and `False` otherwise.  It has the added benefit of quitting early if any value is `False`, unlike `min` which must run through the entire sequence at least once.

If you find that you need to evaluate if the are all `False`, I recommend [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) (well, `not any(...)`, specifically) which has a similar "quit as soon as possible" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for **[all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)** built-in function:

```
print all(f() for f in [foo, bar, baz])
```